# After moving Android Studio project to a different computer, the app wont run

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I moved a project to a different computer by copying it to a flash drive and pasting it onto the new computer, and now when I try to run the app, it just says "App has stopped".

I already did Build > Clean Project, then Build > Build APK.
I haven't made any other changes to the code, and it ran fine on the old computer. How do I fix this?

Comment: If your app stopped, that means there is stacktrace. So add the stacktrace and add your code. Othervise noone on stackoverflow can help you. Stacktrace: logcat. Code: add the relevant code the stacktrace points to

Comment: try re-building the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the build.gradle files and the version of your sdk i think that will help you out...for example if the current sdk version is 25 and the copied file has 23 you need to change it to 25 to make it run
don't forget to sync and clean the project